# how to connect to a bit torrent tracker in c

Tags: c, tcp, udp, bittorrent, tracker

I am tying to connect to a bit torrent tracker, http://tracker.thepiratebay.org. The gethostbyname() keeps returning null, how should I fix this? Also do you see anything else wrong with this code?

```
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr; 
    int portNum = 80;

    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
          printf("fail create socket");
          return 0;
    }

    char *path = "http://tracker.thepiratebay.org/";
    struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(path);   
    if(hp==NULL){
        printf("null");
    else{

        memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));   
        servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 
        memcpy( (char *) &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, (char *)  hp->h_addr, hp->h_length );
        servAddr.sin_port   = htons(portNum);    
    }

    //send request to tracker server 
    if (send(sock, requestToSend, strlen(requestToSend), 0) != strlen(requestToSend)){
        printf("fail send");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And isn't TPB's tracker down for good?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that `http://tracker.thepiratebay.org/` is a URL, but `gethostbyname()` expects just the host name.  The host name is `tracker.thepiratebay.org`.

It would make it much easier if you just use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), which will handle all of that HTTP stuff for you.  It is extremely common to use libcurl in applications that connect to HTTP servers; it is an excellent library.  It's certainly easier than socket programming.

### Use `getaddrinfo()`

The modern alternative to `gethostbyname()` is `getaddrinfo()`.  It's not that `gethostbyname()` doesn't do what you want, rather, `getaddrinfo()` is simply better in every conceivable way.

```
struct addrinfo hint, *ap;
memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
hint.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
int r = getaddrinfo("tracker.thepiratebay.org", "http", &hint, &ap);
```

This will not only get you the address for the host you want, but it will also fill in the port number.  You can use `"http"` as the port, or you can use `"80"` for the port, they are the same thing (as long as `/etc/services` has the right entry).

### Other problems

This line is wrong.

```
memcpy( (char *) &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, (char *)  hp->h_addr, hp->h_length );
```

You don't know that `gethostbyname()` returned an IPv4 address, and it is foolish to try and copy it into a `struct sockaddr_in`.  If `gethostbyname()` returned an IPv6 address, you have just smashed your stack and your program will crash -- or worse, it might not crash.

Either check that it returns an IPv4 address, or simply copy `hp->h_addr` into a generic `struct sockaddr` that was returned from `malloc(hp->h_length)`.  This is a bit ugly but it's the way it goes.

Finally, it is wrong to cast the arguments to `memcpy()`.  It's not an error, but it's wrong.  Don't do it, it can cause otherwise legitimate compiler errors to be suppressed, e.g., if you accidentally cast an `int` to `char *`.

Comment: thanks for reply Dietrich Epp. I can not use any library. Do you know which function I can use to store the url into the &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr.

Comment: @help: You cannot use any library?  Really?  Are you sure?  That sounds really strange.  A lot of people say they can't use libraries, but I'm never sure why and I'm dying to know the reason.

Comment: is for a school project, " must otherwise implement the entire protocol without using any other third party library."

Comment: @help you could let `getaddrinfo()` handle that for you instead

Comment: @user9000: Gah!  I completely missed that this was `gethostbyname()` instead of `getaddrinfo()`.  Nice catch.  I'll edit the answer.